# When I use the paginate of flask_sqlalchemy, can I limit it also?

Tags: limit, flask-sqlalchemy, pagination

My code: `DbVote.query.order_by(
            (something).desc()).paginate(
            page, per_page=5, error_out=False)`

For example, I have 1000 pieces of data, and just whant to get top 500, but I have used paginate, how can I to do?

Comment: The `per_page` defines how many items each page must have.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    DbVote.query.order_by((something).desc())
       .limit(500).from_self()
       .paginate(page, per_page=5, error_out=False)
```